# Suggestions on architecture to monitor services and databases

Tags: java, web-services, monitor

I am trying to make a monitoring system for JAVA web services. It would be a simple switch kind of system where based on the health of a service it would report 'RUNNING', 'CRITICAL' or 'UNSTABLE'. The challenge is integrating it with existing code. While calling an endpoint with the data would be the easiest, I am not too keen on going down that path because it would require too many changes to the source code. Instead I was looking at run-time injection. Your suggestions on coming up with an architecture would be very helpful. Thanks and let me know if you have questions.

EDIT: Tips on how to extend it to monitor stored procedures in an Oracle DB would be great too.

Answer (score -1):

There is a common answer for such kind of question: just try JMX.

If you already use such frameworks like Spring - feel free to use Spring JMX there.
Aslo you can built your application into OSGi framework if it suits to you (here you can also use JMX layer for that).

Comment: Thanks. I thought of JMX but here's the thing. The applications/services would need to be monitored from a remote server so that server needs to connect to each application to retrieve data. However, this cannot be guaranteed on the present systems we have. Second, I just need a status and I think JMX might be an overkill (we are very critical about performance). But this is just my personal opinion.